# Run left / right sprite animation by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, sprite-sheet

I have problem with this sprite animation.
[sprite-sheet](http://www.torbak.com/varie/girl_60x60.png)
The script don't change the correct animation, and the speed increases each time you click in the same direction.

```
<div id="coordinates">MOUSE XY</div>    
<div id="map" style="width:960px; height:80px; background-color:black; ">   
 <div id="player"></div>  
</div>
```

Javascript and Jquery

```
<style> #player{background-image:url('girl_60x60.png'); 
    width:60px; height:60px; position:relative; 
    z-index:12; left:465px;}</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 // click event 
 $('#map').click(function(e) { 
  // take coordinates
  var posX = e.pageX ;
  var posY = e.pageY;
  //print X e Y
  $('#coordinates').html("X: " + posX + " Y: " + posY); 

  if (posX <= 480) {   //Check the click relative to the center.
   setInterval('ani_left()',100); //left animation                          
  } else {              
   setInterval('ani_right()',100); //right animation
  }
}); 

var frame = 1;

// Right animation
function ani_right() {
 var left = 60 * frame;  //next frame every 60px
 var top = 0;
 $('#player').css('backgroundPosition','-'+left+'px -'+top+'px');
 frame++;
}
// left animation
function ani_left() {
 var left = 60 * frame;
 var top = 60;   //second row of frames
 $('#player').css('backgroundPosition','-'+left+'px -'+top+'px');
 frame++;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the execution of previous `setInterval` with `clearInterval(idInterval)`.

I reccomend you to use `setInterval(funcName,100)` and not `setInterval('funcName()',100)`;

```
var idInt = -1; // add this
 // click event 
 $('#map').click(function(e) { 
     if(idInt != -1) 
         clearInterval(idInt); // add this 
/* .. CUT .. */

  if (posX <= 480) {   //Check the click relative to the center.
      idInt = setInterval(ani_left,100); //left animation                          
  } else {              
      idInt = setInterval(ani_right,100); //right animation
  }
}); 

/* cut */
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BJgQz/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your old draw interval before you start a new one

```
var interval;

if (posX <= 480) {   //Check the click relative to the center.
   clearInterval(interval);
   interval = 0;
   interval = setInterval(ani_left,100); //left animation                          
  } else {              
   clearInterval(interval);
   interval = 0;
   interval = setInterval(ani_right,100); //right animation
  }
```

Comment: be careful that you're using the same interval there, if that code is pasted into his code as is, integer will be created each time the user clicks and won't get cleared.

Comment: do you actually tell ani_right or left WHAT sprite they should be drawing... I don't see code doing that

Comment: do you by chance have this setup on a url to take a look at?